# In Android Studio.!

Tags: android

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\Prakash\AndroidStudioProjects\fambas\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-run_941429a62ec15b43aafa06c428d9fea3dfdd45d9\classes.dex'.

How to Overcome this Error.I can't able to run any Android Projects for the Past Two Three days.
Can Anyone help me.?

Comment: Can anyone help me for the above mentioned Post...
Will you guys,.?

Answer (score 0):

Disable your antivirus. It could be blocking it. Weird, but it worked for me. Or add an exception in your av list.